# Should the database service be restarted after performing a restore?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, restore

Given:

- a database backup of >100G uncompressed disk space
- SQL Server 2012 Instance
- Dev/Test system host (Non-production)

Is it better to restart the MS SQL Server, Agent, etc services after restoring the DB? Why or why not?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for restarting database after restore, you would achieve nothing

Comment: generally there are just a few reasons to restart a sql server if you don't have to :) (OS reboot, rebuilt system databses...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to.

Once the database is restored, if over top a previous database or as a new one, there will be no information in cache (or very little). If you were to restart the services, the only thing accomplished is that SQL Server has to run recovery on all of the databases in the instance and re-acquire memory. This would actually cause a detrimental effect, assuming this isn't express edition and the buffer pool is actually being used (i.e. there is more than 1 databases on the system). Even if it were, there is still *no good reason* to do so.